# Kotlin Flow - Android: Application gets stuck in flow combine and does not move ahead

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to combine two flows and then send the value to a function and then collect the result.

My code never goes to second line of combine and never comes to collect results block.

What am I missing can anyone pls explain.

Below is my code:

```
viewModelScope.launch {

            combine(flow1, flow2){ model1: Model1, model2: Model2 ->
                performAction(model1, model2)
            }.collect {list ->
                updateState {
                    copy(isLoading = false, list = list)
                }
            }
        }
```

Code never goes into performAction function and progress keeps loading.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

I'd suspect that one of your flows is actually empty.

Could you ensure that both of them are emitting values?

Comment: How can I check if flow has value?

Comment: I'd suggest to try collecting it individually or using the `first()` operator